# Database design - Field is only applicable when another field has certain code (2NF)

Tags: database, database-design, 3nf

I have the following table design:

```
 TABLE: WORK_ACTION_CLASS 
 WORK_ACTION_CLASS_ID VARCHAR2(24) Primary Key
 NAME VARCHAR2(64)  64 Action Name
 ROLE_CLASS_ID VARCHAR2(24) Role Class ID That Performs This Action  
 CHECKLIST_CLASS_ID VARCHAR2(24) Checklist Class PK  
 WORK_ACTION_TYPE_ID VARCHAR2(3)
```

Where the WORK_ACTION_TYPE_ID is a simpe lookup

```
 1=Done Button
 2=Dynamic Checklist
 3=Custom Form
 4=Progress Log
 5=Approve/Decline Button
```

When the Action Type is a Dynamic Checklist, a `CHECKLIST_CLASS_ID` is required so that the action knows the specifics of a Checklist to use programmatically.  I don't like this design because if this Action Definition is not a Dynamic Checklist, `CHECKLIST_CLASS_ID` field is not applicable.  I don't know the best way to separtate this fact out.

So it might be correct to say that my that my table is 2NF not 3NF. If so, how do I or should I try to get to 3NF??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a table for dynamic checklists.

```
create table work_action_dynamic_checklists (
  work_action_class_id varchar2(24) primary key,
  work_action_type_id varchar2(3) not null
    default '2'                                  -- ???
    check(work_action_type_id = '2'),
  checklist_class_id varchar2(24) not null,
  foreign key (work_action_class_id, work_action_type_id) 
    references work_action_class (work_action_class_id, work_action_type_id)
);
```

For that to work, you need to add a unique constraint on {work_action_class_id, work_action_type_id} in work_action_class.  This guarantees that rows in *this* table always reference a row in work_action_class that has work_action_type_id = '2'.

But unless you implement other changes, too, you lose the ability to require a checklist_class_id for every row that has a work_action_type_id of '2'. (A CHECK() constraint can fix that in the original table.) You could attack that problem with triggers or updatable views.

Comment: yeah I guesss that makes sense to separate out checklist class id.  I could have my Java web application help with some of the logic you are suggesting with triggers, checks and constraints.